# Cannot pass messages from Webpage to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`Want.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Text</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("go");
            var id = "lmeobdocdijngimfmndbaljkejddkpbc"
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(id, { data: "Todo" },
                function(response){
                    if(response == undefined){
                        console.log("Message didnt cross site");
                        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                    }
                }

            )};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I made a chrome extention and want to send a message to my extensions background script to do stuff with a click of a button as seen. The extension id is labeled as `id`

This is my `background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.data === "Todo") {
            alert("Listened");                
            sendResponse({ data: "money" });

        });
```

Here is my `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "E",
  "description": "P",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",

  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["https://google.com/myindex/Want.html"]
  }
}
```

However, when i try to run the connect, I get `Message didn't cross site` and the error `Object {message: "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."}`

Any clue as to why this is working as I have been exhausting the chrome docs and they all say this is proper.

Comment: You're obviously getting a response though, so it must be getting to background.js ... or maybe not now that I've re-read your code

Comment: @JaromandaX I didnt think so. According to the docs, the callback is formatted like this  _The JSON response object sent by the handler of the message. If an error occurs while connecting to the extension, the callback will be called with no arguments and runtime.lastError will be set to the error message._

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is the following line:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["https://google.com/myindex/Want.html"]
}
```

`"https://google.com/myindex/Want.html"` doesn't match any valid url, you should use something like `https://*.google.com/myindex/Want.html` or `*://*.google.com/myindex/Want.html` if you are sure that `Want.html` is under google host.

Comment: Sorry but I changed the line to because im connnecting to my own web service. specifically `https://Stevie.dmnnt.msft/myindex/Want.html`. However I did try to change it to `*://*.dmnnt.msft/myindex/Want.html.` Still no avail

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution. Problem is instead of all that, its better just to specify anything coming from a domain. `*//Stevie.dmnnt.msft/*` worked.